# JavaScript: what is the regex to trim other than A-Z a-z 0-9 and symbols?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, node.js

Reading some text file by `fs` of node.js/Windows results awkward data that contains invisible characters.

`String.length` indicates the data contains many redundant invisible characters.

Trying to trim by js `String.trim` does not work well, so I try to remove them using `String.replace` with regex.

So, here's my question.

what is the regex to trim other than A-Z a-z 0-9 and symbols?

Space should be preserved (not the target to trim).

Thanks.

Comment: Try `/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/`

Comment: [^\w] should do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a negated class like:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9\s]
```

Btw, you also can shorten it to:

```
[^A-Za-z\d\s]
```

And.. if you don't mind to preserve underscores your could use:

```
[^\w\s]
```

The idea of the negated class is to not match the characters in it. For this regex:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9\s]
```

it means:

```
^       ---> not match the following
A-Za-z  ---> letters from a-z insensitive
\d      ---> digits from 0 to 9
\s      ---> spaces, tabs, etc (whitespaces)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/pJ4bH2/1)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add your symbols to the class you have designated as non-replacable.

[^a-zA-Z0-9\s  `add symbols here`]+